# jquery- passing values between two tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table and I need to put into row values from other table (from selected row in this table) after button clicked. Table with values is hiden until I click button "Add". I'm trying with storing last clicked row index number in first table, variable is declared on top of script but inside function value of it is *udnefined*.

code for getting row index:

```
var rowSelected = 1;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).delegate('tr', 'click', function (event) {
        rowSelected = $(this).closest("tr")[0].rowIndex;
    });
});
```

Function after 'click' row inside table with value to pass:

```
$('#tablica_produktow').on('click','tr',function(){
        var wiersz = $(this).find('td').map(function(){
            return $.trim($(this).text())
        })
        $('input[name="products['+rowSelected+'][prod_name]"]').val(wiersz[1]); //rowSelected is *undefined*
        $('input[name="products['+ rowSelected +'][prod_metr]"]').val(wiersz[2]);
        $('input[name="products['+rowSelected+'][prod_pricentax]"]').val(wiersz[3]);      
        $("#wczytaj_produkt").dialog("close");
        calculate();
    })
```

How I can do this?

For better view:

on this page http://bergamot.com.pl/sklep/oferty/start/ is field named "Produkty" with button "Dodaj z bazy". This button will open second table and I need to pass data from clicked row to inputs inside field "Produkty".

Comment: We need some code or link to live example

Comment: Also, it seems you have two click-handlers defined on tr-tags, one 'global' and one defined for the table #tablica_produktow? Tr-tags inside this table may trigger *two* click events

Comment: show some html... if you are clicking on 2 tables will change `rowSelected` when click either table... need to delegate `rowSelected` clcik handler only to one table (I think). A demo in jsfiddle.net would really help